# Moment.js, date (MM-YYYY) normal comparison not correct

Tags: javascript, date, comparison, momentjs

I'm generating a dynamic transaction data table in my app. In this table every month sould be seperated and a total row should be added after the month.

My version worked until the year changed. December 2016 and January 2017 are not getting seperated because the comparison isn't made correct.

Simplified I'm doing the following:

```
var dateNow = moment("2016-12-21T13:14:55").format("MM-YYYY");
var lastDate = moment("2017-01-13T14:23:12").format("MM-YYYY");

if(lastDate > dateNow) // This is false
{
  // This isn't executed
}
```

Why is the comparison false? It works for all other months.

The moment.js version I'm using is 2.7.0.

Comment: both lastDate and dateNow are strings. There only string comparison happening

Comment: But shouldn't moment.js convert them to date? :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
var before = "12-2016";
var after = "01-2017"

var beforeInMoment = moment.utc(before, "MM-YYYY");
var afterInMoment = moment.utc(after, "MM-YYYY");

if(beforeInMoment.isBefore(afterInMoment)){
  console.log('Yes');
}
```

Comment: I found a solution because you told me it was a string comparison. Just did it like this: `moment(moment("2017-01-13T14:23:12").format("MM-YYYY"), "MM-YYYY")` :) Thank you very much!